# How to edit all formulas in a column except for totals

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

The excel sheet below has a "header" row, and a combination of "regular" rows and "subtotal" rows.

**Is there a way to edit the formula for a cell**, for example the one clicked in the screenshot below, **and have the formula updated for all the other rows**, **without affecting the header and subtotal rows**?

Only way I know now is to edit it, and then copy one and then paste it onto all the others, which is quite a pain when I have to manually select them all specifically to not also paste on top of the subtotal rows...

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Enable filtering. Set filter to `%` column showing only empty cells. Results rows will be hidden. Alter first cell (D2) as you need. Drag formula over visible cells. Remove filter.

Comment: @Akina - Why don't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest you VBA (Macro), will help you to convert specific Cell/Range of cells into `Value` to make the Formula non calculative.*

```
Sub FormulatoValue()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range

On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "Formula to Value"

Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each Rng In WorkRng
    Rng.Value = Rng.Text
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**How it works:**

1. Copy & Paste this Code as Standard Module with the Sheet.
2. When Macro display the `Input Box` you may click Cell or Rage of Cell like `A1, A4, A2:F2, A2:A10`.
3. Finish with `Ok`.

**N.B.** *This sample code will help you to restore the Formula in specific Cell/Range of Cells.*

```
Sub displayformula()
If Range("A2") <> "" Then Range("A2").Formula = "=Average(H1:H6)"
If Range("A2:F2") <> "" Then Range("A2:F2").Formula = "=Average(H1:H6)"
End Sub
```

*Adjust Cell references in the code as needed.*